# WHERE clause that's stored in a table: Use it to filter a layer?

Tags: filter, oracle-dbms, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, where-clause

I have a [workorder management system](https://www.ibm.com/ca-en/marketplace/maximo) (WMS).

- The WMS has functionality that allows users to [save queries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/configure/t_create_query_prv_app.html).
- The queries are saved in a Oracle database table called `QUERY` (in a `CLAUSE` column).

An example of a value in the `CLAUSE` column would be:

`((woclass = 'WORKORDER' or woclass = 'ACTIVITY') and contains(description,'$paint') > 0  and historyflag = 0 and istask = 0 and siteid = 'SERVICES')`

---

I would like to utilize the saved WMS queries by applying them as **filters to layers in a Portal web map**.

From a drop-down menu, a user would choose a `CLAUSENAME` (from the `QUERY` table), the widget would programmatically extract the WHERE clause value from the `CLAUSE` column, and use it to automatically filter a layer.

To be clear, this would be a programmatic/custom widget solution, not manual copying and pasting.

**Is it possible to do this?**

Comment: Totally possible. You just need to construct your SQL statement to include the chosen filter clause. Unless I miss something, this is trivial

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind : I edited the question to try to make it clearer that I'd like a custom widget to do this programmatically, not the user to do it manually with copy/paste. In hindsight, I might need to rewrite the question.

Comment: There was never a question about the user doing any copy / pasting. The user selects the filters to apply (drop down list or similar) and the application then constructs the proper SQL statement and sends it for execution to the database